# TYPO3 v12 Form problems

Tags: typo3, typo3-12.x, typo3-form

I am using the TYPO3 Form extension for my contact form. It is a simple form with input fields name, subject, email and message. Validator for email field is also included. I created a form element on my page and selected the mentioned form. It appears correctly on the screen but there is following problem: When submitting, nothing happens. The page just gets reloaded and that's it. No error messages in the console or in the logs. What is more, the validator for the email input field also does not work. I can enter any string or numbers I want and get no warning that the format is wrong.

Correct finisher for sending emails to a specific email adress is also added. The extension is also added to the template. What am I missing? I have the exactly same form in another TYPO3 installation, but this one has TYPO3 v10 installed. Here, everything works perfectly. When testing the email sending in TYPO3 (v12), everything works fine. A testmail is sent successfully to the entered email.

I would appreciate any hints, what the problem could be or steps that I could try to identify the problem.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: sending mails may be intercepted at different stations. maybe the sender (domain) doesn't match the system and the mail is not send or not accepted from receiving system. Validation could be done on client side (then check for javascript errors in the browser console) or the server (then an explicit log of any input is needed, otherwise the behaviour might be correct and no (error) log written. there should be an error handling (output) in the form.

Comment: Did you by chance installed the add on "derhansen/form_crshield", I had some likewise issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers.

I finally solved the problem:
The form was placed on a subpage in TYPO3. For some reason, the problems above occured. When moving the form onto the root page, suddenly everything worked fine.

I don't know, why the form does not work on subpages, but moving it to the main page was the solution in my case.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that you have accidentally filled the honeypot field. Submitting a form with a filled honeypot field leads to the behavior you describe. As a simple test you can submit the form again without any change and should see your expected result.

This usually happens when using browser extensions to fill form fields with random input for testing purposes. Also regular browser autofill may be the culprit here.

There is not really a solution here, you can try [turning the honeypot field into a real `hidden` field](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/12.4/en-us/I/Config/proto/formElements/formElementTypes/Honeypot/properties/renderAsHiddenField.html?highlight=honeypot) which would definitely prevent autofill by browser extensions. But this in turn would also reduce the chance of spam bots filling this field, so you will likely see an increase of form spam after this.